# When to use *this?

Tags: c++

Hello im studing classes and i have the following code :

```
Sales_Data & Sales_Data::combine(const Sales_Data & rhs){
units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
revenue += rhs.revenue;
return *this;  }
```

I would like to know why we use `return *this`, and  `Sales_Data &`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this when you need to return a reference to yourself. You typically see it in operator overloading, so that the result can return itself:

```
Foo &operator=(const Foo &rhs)
{
  // Whatever...
  return *this;
}
```

By doing this it allow you to easily chain calls:

```
a=b=c;
```

Whereas if returned a pointer it would look messy.

It's also commonly used in fluid api design so that you can combine calls. Using your example you could write:

```
Sales_Data x,y,z;

x.combine(y).combine(z);
```

However, if does loose a bit of its elegance when you've got a pointer lurking around:

```
  Sales_Data *x=LoadSalesData();
  Sales_Data y,z;

  x->combine(y).combine(z);
```

Answer (score 7):

Doing so you can run multiple combines in one statement:

```
Sales_Data d1, d2, d3;
d1.combine(d2).combine(d3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `*this` to return a reference to current object.

This is usually useful to allow method chaining:

```
rhs1.combine(rhs2).combine(rhs3);
```

A well known example of this is the `operator<<` of streams, that returns a reference to the stream object to make concatenation of outputs possible.

```
std::cout << "first" << "second";
```

Comment: I think you mean method chaining, not "function concatenation"

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Downvoting without a comment is a very bad habit. I just hate it.